# Making a window always stay behind

Tags: python, winapi

On Windows 10, I'm trying to make a window stay always on bottom; that is, it is always shown behind other windows and can't be brought on top of them. I've seen around that the easiest solution is to make the window a child of the desktop; however, I've had mixed success in doing this. The undesirable side effects of making a window child of the desktop are not a problem in this case. I've tried making my window child of SysListView32, SHELLDLL_DefView and Progman.
In the first two cases, the window does correctly stay behind, though for some reason it is partially transparent and the desktop background can be seen behind it (but not whatever files/folders may be on the desktop). In the last case the window can't be seen at all. Is there some way to take care of the transparency issue, or am I not making my window child of the right window? If it matters, I'm using Python 3.7 with Pygame (which is based on SDL) to create my window.

Comment: Your attempt is fundamentally flawed on a technical level (see [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)). It's also fundamentally flawed on a logical level (see [What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)). It's unclear, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, since you explained your proposed solution rather than the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: All I would like to do is make a window be shown behind the others. I understand that, of course, it's not always possible for it to be behind in case another window uses the same method to be behind every other as well, but for me it's acceptable since it seems like a fairly rare case.

Comment: Presumably, that's *not* all you want. Reading into your question, you also seem to want your window to not show up in the [Alt]+[Tab]/[Win]+[Tab] list of windows. Probably more, too. But as I said, you have explained your solution without ever stating your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I would think of it as a separate issue. Also, making the window child of the desktop automatically solved that issue, also removing the window from the taskbar. My final goal would be to make some kind of fake desktop, which is why I need the window to be shown last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding another solution, I've managed to fix the transparency issue by enabling the extended window style WS_EX_LAYERED on my window using SetWindowLong.